# Recyclerview move to and visibility going off-screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I set something visible in my recycler view `"visibility = VISIBLE"` it goes offscreen if its close to bottom or top, I wanted to know if is there any way to make the `recyclerview` focus in it when `VISIBLE` is called.

Another problem I have is with move to `"(ctx as MainActivity).moveTo(id.toInt() + 7)"`  << for those who asked moveTo jumps to target item in the recycler view.

I am having a hard time to make it look good and jump to the right spot, I think the toolbar with `"app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways""` might be messing with it.

I tried adding numbers to the move-to and I managed to make the keyboard move things up when opened to keep focus on edit text but couldn't solve the other problems.

The toolbar

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:title="Gerenciador de Prioridades"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

On top of that I get some null error first time I try to use moveto so I made an if to avoid it and +7 to make sure it goes down, dont know if it's the best approach.

```
if (id != 1.toLong()) {
            (ctx as MainActivity).moveTo(id.toInt() + 7)
        }
```

I really appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide.

Edit : 
[image]

When this item is too close to the botom and with visibility GONE it goes offscreen when I click it for visibility = VISIBLE , so im wondering if there is anyway to make it go up or something to keep it inside the scroll view but visible for the user.

Comment: can u share the screenshot of the current UI?

Comment: What is moveTo?. please present whole necessary stuff and screenshots

Comment: Move to in a recycle view main activity moves to the item in the recyclerview list. Ill try to add screenshots shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use include to place you view in the app bar layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:title="Gerenciador de Prioridades"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Then add your views to the content main layout , this should fix the issue